# Finding solutions to Boolean satisfaction problems

Tags: computational-complexity, satisfiability

How hard is it to find a solution to an instance of **SAT** if we know that the instance is satisfiable?

Clearly, finding a solution to a **SAT** instance is at least as hard as deciding whether the instance has a solution and is therefore **NP**-hard. Can we say the same about the problem of finding a solution to a **SAT** instance, given that we know that such a solution exists?

Comment: Finding a solution is no harder than finding that there is a solution. Given than you have some magic algorithm to verify that some solution exists, but without building the solution, you can turn it into an algorithm to find a solution as follows: set the first bit to 1. Is there a solution? If not, set it to 0. Then repeat, going one bit at a time.

Answer (score 1):

It's just as hard to find a solution, if you're promised that a solution exists, then to check whether a solution exists.

In particular, suppose you have an efficient algorithm $A$ to find a solution to any CNF formula if you're promised that it is satisfiable.  Suppose I want to know whether $\varphi$ has a satisfiable or not.  Then I can run your algorithm $A$ on $\varphi$, and see what happens.  If it outputs a solution, I can check whether it satisfies $\varphi$; if yes, then I know that $\varphi$ is satisfiable or not.  Otherwise, if it outputs something that is not a valid solution, or it crashes, or its exceeds the running time bounds for $A$, then I know that $\varphi$ is not satisfiable.

Why does this work?  Well, if $\varphi$ actually is satisfiable, then your $A$ will find a solution, and so my method will correctly output that $\varphi$ is satisfiable.  If $\varphi$ is not satisfiable, then $A$ will either fail to output anything or output something that is not a satisfying assumption (remember, there is no solution, so no matter what $A$ outputs, it can't possibly satisfy $\varphi$), so my method will correctly output that $\varphi$ is not satisfiable.  Either way, my method will find the answer, and its running time will be not much longer than the running time of $A$.

This reduction proves that your problem is just as hard as SAT.  So if P!=NP, then there is no polynomial-time algorithm for your problem.